# Is there a way to assert that someone entered the correct code with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

For the past two years, I've used a program called CodeKeyz in my classroom to teach code syntax while I was freed up to exclusively teach the computational thinking aspect of python.

Welp. They're gone. I still have the modules, but I can't actually edit them or change anything, and I'm anticipating them being gone forever soon.

So I'm building a new suite with pytest.

(If you have alternative ideas for doing this kind of teaching, I'm all ears. It's very effective at getting them able to code in python, and I really don't want to give it up, but I don't have a choice.)

I've used TDD in the past, but I'm not sure how to go about this one. I'm looking to see if what a student adds to the code is identical to what I want it to be.

This is the code I have in main.py

```
def print1(x):
 return print("Hello world")
```

This is what I have in the testing page.

```
def test_print1():
  assert print1 is "Hello world"
```

I'm fairly certain this is wrong.

What I want it to do is show me that they've put in

```
print("Hello world")
```

Once I get one of these successful, I can get the rest of them. It shouldn't be hard. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to check that the function _definition in the source code contains_ the `print("Hello world")` or do you want to check the side effect of that _executing_ the function  will output the string `Hello world`? I.e. you want something along `with contextlib.redirect_stdout() as s: print1() assert s == "Hello world"` or you want `assert 'print("Hello world")' in inspect.getsource(print1)`?

Comment: @KamilCuk The answer to that is "Yes." I'm trying to make sure the output is the same, and also that they are putting in the correct code. Effectively, they're supposed to be getting practice writing syntax, independently from computational thinking.

Comment: I can recommend some motivation by suggesting the rudimentary implementation of [pythonlings](https://github.com/sigmages/pythonlings) which is based on the [rustlings](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings) small exercises. These are command line tools that teach concepts by exercises. The student's goal is to fix the bugs (make the tests green) in the exercise files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to check that executing will output the string

Then you have to temporarily redirect the standard output stream of your program to a temporary string and execute the function and compare the result..

```
def test_print1():
   with contextlib.redirect_stdout(io.StringIO()) as f:
       print1()
   assert f.getvalue() == "Hello world"
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout

Comment: The problem now is that it's giving me a "Hello world\n" instead of just a "Hello world" and throwing an error. Just gotta figure out how to tell StringIO to not include the newline.

Comment: You really want to really make StringIO not to include newline? Why not just remove newlines from the result? Why not compare with the newline? `print("Hello world"` is not `print("hello world", end="")`. Why not compare with a regex? Etc.

Comment: I fixed it. Just stripped the newline with an .rstrip().